# Import a csv.gzip from Google Storage to CloudSQL

Tags: postgresql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, csv-import

I would like to import daily 10 Go of data from Google Storage to PostgreSQL and define a column as a primary key.

I have 19 compressed csv files and each of them weight 135 Mo. It takes about 35 seconds to import one file (11 minutes in total). The command to import a file:

```
gcloud sql import csv instance-name gs://bucket/file.csv.gzip --database=database --table=table --quiet
```

When I add directly the primary key in cloudsql at the end of the command, it takes 30 minutes. The command to add a primary key:

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

Is it possible to speed up these two operations?

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your case on my GCP instance following the best practices [1] that the documentation suggested and the guide to import a CSV into a CloudSQL database[2].

In summary, the best practices and steps mentions:

1. Upload your CSV file into a bucket in GCP
2. Compress your CSV file to.gz
3. Create the database and the table structure before importing

I generated a compressed CSV file with size of 35Mb~ and upload it into a Storage bucket, as mentioned in the guide. Then, I created my database and table structure in CloudSQL using Postgresql. From there I followed the guide and ran the same command as you had:

```
gcloud sql import csv instance-name gs://bucket/file.csv.gzip --database=database --table=table --quiet
```

I got almost the same timing results as you did so It means that we are doing the best we can do in timing effort for this command.

For the next one,

```
ALTER TABLE table ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

I tried by adding the constraint before importing the CSV (along when I ran the commands for the table definition) and it worked correctly and the command ran in 1 sec on my instance. I then imported the CSV and it worked without issues. 
Please have in mind that If you run the command after the table was created, then all the rows must be processed to see if they are eligible for the constraint, which can cause some delay if there are millions of rows. For more information, please refer to

> “ADD table_constraint [ NOT VALID ]”

from the postgresql documentaion: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html#AEN64781

Please let me know your thoughts.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/#best_practices_for_importing_and_exporting

[2] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/importing#csv

Comment: I've already tried to add the primary key before importing the files but the time to import all files remains the same (about 50 minutes).
For each file I import, all rows are processed to check the constraint and the importing time of each file becomes increasingly longer (the first file takes 50 secondes, the second file 2 minutes, ...).

I've also tried "ADD table_constraint NOT VALID", but it's only to check constraints or foreign key.

Comment: I see. It looks like this is an expected behavior in GCP and looks like this is more on how Postgresql handles data. I found some tips for long running imports for MySQL [1] that may be helpful.

Please let me know your thoughts

[1] https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/import-export/#tips_for_long-running_import_and_export_processes